# All Wi-Fi channels experience interference at a periodic rate for several seconds causing very poor internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, interference

I am having a weird issue and I'm looking for some advice or a direction to be pointed. I recently moved into a new apartment and after setting up internet I have noticed the following issue.

At a rate of approximately 13-15s every single wifi channel (1-11 on 2.4GHz and 36-161 on 5GHz) will become essentially dead for a few seconds before working again.  This includes channels that no other routers are using.  I verified that the problem was related to wifi and not the modem or internet provider by disconnecting the router from the modem, connecting my laptop to the router via Wi-Fi, then "pinging" the router (via the terminal, e.g. ping 192.168.0.1). I repeated the experiment using all Wi-Fi channels and multiple different routers. I also spot checked multiple laptops to make sure the issue wasn't my laptop (the problem persists for laptops and my phone when connected to Wi-Fi).

An example of what I'll see is listed below (again this is for all Wi-Fi channels). Note the portions I have indented. The same behavior is observed for all channels.

Initially I just accepted that Wi-Fi sucks at my new apartment, but after talking to one of the maintenance employees for my apartment in passing (unrelated issue) I became aware of the fact that the complex has had issues with people using jammers in the past. Is this possible given what I am observing? What really stands out to me is how periodic the interference is (it is always there) and the fact that the interference is not localized to a single or handful of adjacent channels.  However, if it was jamming I would expect the Wi-Fi to never work (why jam every 15s?).

I've been thinking about contacting the FCC (we have also noticed trouble with cell phone calls though it might be a coincidence), but I don't want to do that and have this turn out to be something environmental. That said, are there any environmental explanations for what I am seeing? Things like microwaves, baby monitors, etc don't make sense to me because the interference is extremely periodic and across all channels. If there are no environmental reasons, does jamming make sense? If not jamming or environmental what could it be? If anyone has any ideas about this or suggestions of who to possibly contact please let me know (we have tried our internet provider and they were not remotely helpful; we tested your modem remotely and there is nothing wrong lol).

Edit:
I have tested the connection via ethernet and there are no problems. Also, I have tested using multiple routers.  The same problem persists.

```
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=103 ttl=64 time=11.068 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=104 ttl=64 time=8.167 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=105 ttl=64 time=5.174 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=106 ttl=64 time=339.517 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=107 ttl=64 time=352.623 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=108 ttl=64 time=712.207 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=109 ttl=64 time=675.107 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=110 ttl=64 time=74.835 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=111 ttl=64 time=8.906 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=112 ttl=64 time=4.088 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=113 ttl=64 time=6.189 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=114 ttl=64 time=10.935 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=115 ttl=64 time=10.950 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=116 ttl=64 time=8.629 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=117 ttl=64 time=8.150 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=118 ttl=64 time=10.277 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=119 ttl=64 time=22.337 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=120 ttl=64 time=8.528 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=121 ttl=64 time=10.401 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=122 ttl=64 time=337.904 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=123 ttl=64 time=345.829 ms
    Request timeout for icmp_seq 124
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=124 ttl=64 time=1415.580 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=125 ttl=64 time=412.551 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=126 ttl=64 time=10.033 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=127 ttl=64 time=9.157 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=128 ttl=64 time=15.268 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=129 ttl=64 time=15.368 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=130 ttl=64 time=177.083 ms      spike probably caused by collision with another router; included to show normal behavior
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=131 ttl=64 time=20.997 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=132 ttl=64 time=5.688 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=133 ttl=64 time=6.730 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=134 ttl=64 time=4.336 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=135 ttl=64 time=7.878 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=136 ttl=64 time=4.385 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=137 ttl=64 time=12.397 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=138 ttl=64 time=277.556 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=139 ttl=64 time=291.228 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=140 ttl=64 time=1371.166 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=141 ttl=64 time=621.997 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=142 ttl=64 time=24.271 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=143 ttl=64 time=21.720 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=144 ttl=64 time=5.121 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=145 ttl=64 time=8.351 ms
```

Comment: "the complex has had issues with people using jammers in the past." Looks like you need to do re3search to verify that and then to contact the FCC. Not much can be done from this site.

Comment: To really rule connection issues out, connect one of your laptops to the router via ethernet, then check whether or not the problem persists. If you've got the very same issues while using a connection via cable, you just found your culprit.

Comment: Do you have an Ethernet connection in your apartment?  If so, can you substitute a different router?

Comment: @Robidu I have already tested ethernet.  I forgot to add it to my post.  See my edit.

Comment: @John, I have tried multiple routers.  Same problem.

Comment: Then you have some outside interference - you need someone to test this for you.

Comment: I could come up with a variety of reasons: Switching power supplies, PLC in your local power grid, QRM... there are a lot of possibilities here so it would be necessary to rule them all out one by one. For starters you should try to pull the power cord of your Wifi router through a ferrite core to prevent any spurious signals from reaching it, then also make sure to completely reset it (that is, have it completely unplugged for *at least 1 minute* and then replug it). It is best installed as close to the chassis of the router as possible to prevent the cable from becoming a receiving antenna.

Answer (score 1):

Wideband wireless interference wide enough to disrupt both 2.4GHz and 5GHz spectrums would be very rare in my opinion. It could potentially be malicious activity by someone using a wideband RF jammer, but in that case I would expect more complete disruption of your wireless. After all, that is the purpose of a jammer. Assuming you live in the U.S., jammers aren’t legal to purchase and have to be purchased from overseas. It seems like a far stretch that this is, in fact, wireless interference.

I could easily accept that one band or the other is having intermittent issues. It is a well known fact that the 2.4GHz band is saturated. So many cheap, poorly designed routers and other consumer electronics are trouncing on each other that in any moderately populated area it is practically unusable.  I have apartment buildings 100+ feet from my home and the 2.4GHz band is completely unusable.

The very consistent pattern demonstrated would suggest the source is elsewhere. It seems like you have been thorough in your investigation to eliminate different variables. But ultimately, if you want to measure RF interference you need a spectrum analyzer. They aren’t particularly cheap, and range anywhere from a couple hundred bucks for a cheap one to thousands of dollars for top end ones. This is the only way to be sure it is not RF interference. A wideband signal capable of disrupting both Wi-Fi bands every 15 seconds would be clearly visible on a spectrum analyzer and would even be able to help identify the source by measuring signal amplitudes.

But I suspect we must be overlooking something here. You are using cheap, consumer grade wireless routers and Wi-Fi adapters. There are so many things that can go wrong. But, one thing that comes to mind is if you are running any other network monitoring software on your computer while you are running your tests? Anything attempting to measure or monitor your wireless connection could actually be causing the problem.

One example is Windows periodically scans for Wi-Fi networks. For instance, if you run a ping test and open your wireless settings to view nearby wireless networks you will see instability in your network connection. Cheap, consumer grade Wi-Fi adapters cannot scan for wireless networks and maintain network communication at the same time. Many cannot operate on two different bands at the same time either. Scanning all channels on both bands causes disruption to the internet connection.

The problem you describe almost sounds like this. It’s a real problem for people. I suggest making sure all applications are closed and only running the ping test. You can also read about the issue with wireless network scanning and free software (WLAN Optimizer) that can disable it here: https://www.ghacks.net/2011/12/13/how-to-disable-wlan-background-scans/.

> Users have reported connection issues for up to five seconds during scans which is especially problematic for Internet gamers and users who use streaming media services.

You can use WLAN Optimizer to disable background scanning and enable streaming mode. Coupled with shutting down any other running applications and open windows, this would be a good next step in troubleshooting. I have not used this software in the past so hopefully it works for you.

To eliminate potential software issues, which as hard as it is to believe, I think it is, you can also try a [Windows Clean Boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd#ID0EBBD=Windows_10) or [Safe Mode with Networking](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234).

You can also find a bunch of other search results and solutions from people experiencing the same issue.

https://www.google.com/search?q=wifi+lag+every+15+seconds

Comment: Some "prosumer" Wi-Fi access points have basic spectrum analyzers in them (because it's something that Atheros 2.4GHz Wi-Fi chips could do) – e.g. I have a Mikrotik RB951G as a Wi-Fi router and its SSH interface has `/interface wireless spectral-history` which does [basically that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKkMm.png), and we keep an ancient PicoStationM2 AP in the drawer for its [airView feature](https://i.imgur.com/PkyNMrj.png). Either of them is not a professional tool by any means, but can be found for under $100 and likely could still reveal such interference.